# Function not printing to console within a for loop

Tags: r

I have a data frame with six columns. When I write this in an R script and run it:

```
any(is.na(df[ , 1]))
```

I get back exactly the output I expect in the console window. And that holds for any of the six columns.

When I try to examine all six columns via a function, however, like this:

```
for (i in 1:6){
  any(is.na(df[ , i]))
}
```

All I get in the console window is this:

```
> for (i in 1:6){
+   any(is.na(df[ , i]))
+ }
```

I feel as though I'm missing some critical little piece of information, but I'm not able to figure it out through the online documentation I've come across.

Comment: You're not storing the result or printing it.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question. Typing `any(is.na(df[,1]))` at the command line generates `[1] FALSE`. Running the loop above generates no output. It's not obvious why unless you know the answer, and *the documentation is poor on this*. Within loops and scripts you need to explicitly send to output using, e.g. `print(...)`.

Comment: More R-like code would be to use `apply` style loops, e.g. `sapply(mtcars, function(x) any(is.na(x)))`.

Comment: Or using even more functional programming: `library(functional); sapply(mtcars, Compose(is.na, any))`. This kind of functional style works really well with R, leading to short to-the-point code. If you are just delving into R, I would definitely recommend learning R from a functional perspective, i.e. using `*apply` style loops and such. See e.g. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra: Great link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing some output. Currently, your R code does not spit anything out. What you see in the console is correct.

```
for (i in 1:6){
  print(any(is.na(df[ , i])))
}
```